# action.setcallback doesnt get exeucted from Helper. It works fine from controller

Tags: lightning

action.setcallback doesnt get exeucted from Helper. It works fine from controller
I am trying to call a server side method in apex class from lightning controller
It works fine from javascript controller but code doesnt get executed from helper
I want to execute code from helper because i need to call helper function based on some other event. Code from helper is pasted below.

```
helper.callserver(cmp,lat,lang);
({
    callserver : function(cmp,strlat,strlang) {
                    alert('inside helper callserver function call cmp is>>' + cmp +'<<');
                    var action = cmp.get("c.getLatLang");
                    alert('after getnearestvehicles call');
                    //action.setParams({"strlat":"51117320","strlang":"6789550"});
                    //alert('after setparams call');
                    action.setCallback(this, function(a){
                        alert('INSIDE SETCALLBACK ACTION MAP CLICK');
                        var strLatLang1 = a.getReturnValue();
                       alert("STR LAT LANG1 is>>>" + strLatLang1 + '<<<');
                    });
            $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Comment: Is the function in helper getting called at all? Are you getting the alerts?

Comment: all alerts are working fine. I can see value for cmp also. control goes inside helper. code before action.setcallback gets executed properly.

Comment: Not sure how relevant it is, but can you check if the status is SUCCESS or not inside setCallback? use `if(a.getState() === "SUCCESS")`

Comment: it doesnt go inside action.setcallback hence state is not shown i had put alert on state also earlier

Answer (score 1):

Please, try below code. If this is not working propertly you should add code where you call helper method.

controller

```
controllerFunctionCallServer : function(component, event, helper) { 
    var strlat = '51117320';
    var strlang = '6789550';
    helper.callserver(component, strlat, strlang);  
}
```

helper

```
callserver : function(component, strlat, strlang) {

    var action = component.get("c.getLatLang");

    action.setParams({ 
        strlat : strlat,
        strlang : strlang
    });

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            alert("From server: " + response.getReturnValue());
            var strLatLang1 = response.getReturnValue();
            alert("STR LAT LANG1 is>>>" + strLatLang1 + '<<<');
        } else  {
            console.log("Calback errror!!");
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

Maybye you miss something for example 'helper' in controller. function(component, event, **helper**)

OR

you don't have define variable in controller **strlat** or **strlang**

OR

you have diferent problem with call helper method.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer as of now.

From the documentation,

> setCallback() has a third parameter that registers the action state
>   that invokes the callback. If you don't specify the third argument for
>   setCallback(), it defaults to registering the SUCCESS and ERROR
>   states. To set a callback for another state, such as ABORTED, you can
>   call setCallback() multiple times with the action state set explicitly
>   in the third argument.

For example:

> action.setCallback(this, function(response) { ...}, "ABORTED");

So its a possibility that the request is having status ABORT or INCOMPLETE. You may want to write another setCallback with the 3rd parameter and check the state of the request.

Here is the [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm)

Comment: Even with third parameter as ABORTED it doesnt go inside action.setcallback

Comment: I have tried with INCOMPLETE also and it doesnt go inside action.setcallback

Comment: This callback works fine when i am doing it from javascript controller. It is not working from helper. Do we need to consider something if we have to invoke action callback from helper? Any thoughts?

Comment: this callback doesn't work also from other javascript function defined inside javascript controller.

Comment: has anybody seen similar behaviour before? can anybody answer this?